# MySQL Update query using equals (=) and LIKE with alphanumeric criteria value

Tags: php, php-7, redbean

Recently noticed that a working `UPDATE` query has no longer same results with where clause that contains alphanumeric values leading with number, appreciate any help.

`UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE `user` SET last_name = 'newTest' where `identifier` = '123abc';
```

**ISSUE**: This query updates all records with `identifier` begins with 123...

Fixed temporary the issue by using `LIKE` (see below):

```
UPDATE `user` SET last_name = 'newTest' where `identifier` LIKE '123abc';
```

But afraid there is some other similar cases in my code that could causes unacceptable data loss for clients.

**EDIT**: 
query with the issue is when I update another identifier that has the exact number leading other identifiers:

```
UPDATE `user` SET last_name = 'newTest' where `identifier` = 123;
```

Tech. versions used: php 7, mysql 5.6, RedBean 5, OS Alpine 3.11

Comment: This would only happen if `identifier` 's data type is not varchar but any numeric data type.

Comment: That's first thing comes to my mind while debugging but i confirm that the issue occurs with `identifier varchar (100)`

Comment: Then this is not a MySql issue: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=99762e19e53bb5944a0cfb10e1f21bb5

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. my guess is php version or the ORM am using Redbean !!?

Comment: I can't say, you will have to check.

Comment: Sorry @forpas i didn't describe well my issue, please find the exact scenario in updated post.

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you compare a string value and a numeric value:

```
where `identifier` = 123
```

so Mysql does an implicit conversion of the column `identifier` to numeric and since the values `123abc` or `123...` start with `123`, they are all converted to `123` and the condition returns `TRUE` for all the values that start with `123`.
You can see this behavior [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qZaBKrQyWF2jrG4FBp53e6/0).
What you want is **string** comparison.
So change to:

```
where `identifier` = '123...'
```

This way you do a string comparison.

Comment: Already try it and it works fine, but actually my question is about handling all other similar cases in a huge code with one shot if possible?

Comment: One shot is not possible if you have hardcoded values. In order to force string comparisons you must add single quotes around all the values.

Comment: Of course there are no hardcoded values and all values are coming as API input parameters. Ok thank you anyway i got your idea.

Comment: For this I can't help you. My answer is about Mysql behavior on implicit conversions.